# MethodNotAllowedHttpException while submitting form with put request in laravel

Tags: laravel

Here is my code in my form

```
<form method="POST" action="{‌{URL::route('updateProduct', [$product-
>product_id]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
...
...
```

Route:

```
Route::put('/updateProduct/{p_id}',[
'as' => 'updateProduct',
'uses'=>'ProductsController@updateProduct'
]);
```

controller:

```
public function updateProduct(Request $request, $p_id)
{
    return "Hello" .$p_id;    
}
```

I get `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 251` all the time i try to access.

Answer (score 0):

You may replace:

```
<form method="POST" 
      action="{‌{URL::route('updateProduct', [$product->product_id]) }}" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

By:

```
<form method="POST" 
      action="/updateProduct/{{$product->product_id}}" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Also, if it still does not work, you may have a look at: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457

Comment: I think {‌{URL::route('updateProduct', [$product->product_id]) }} returns /updateProduct/{{$product->product_id}}. both are same i suppose if you see my route

Comment: Does it work if you try with a POST (instead of a PUT)?

Comment: Ok one more question. Does it work for put if you remove the enctype="multipart/form-data"? If so it's a laravel bug, and I will update my answer.